# Problems with backgrounds and layers (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I have a problem with the background of a View in [this project](https://github.com/dburgosp/ScoreKeeper).

There is one View with a transparent layer, which is not always displayed... It looks like if, in some cases, the height of this View was automatically set to 0, as I can see in the preview of the activity that contains the View. The code of this element is as follows:

```
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="@drawable/background_layers" />
```

The main view group in this activity is a ScrollView. If the whole layout is displayed and is visible on the screen (so you don't need to scroll down) everything works fine (look at the transparent layer, which is the topic of this question):

[image: Vertical orientation: background transparent layer displays correctly]

But if the screen density is low, or if the device is in portrait orientation, and I must use the scroll because the full layout is not displayed at the same time... the previous View is not shown, the transparent layer is not visible :(

[image: Horizontal orientation: background transparent layer is not displayed]

It happens when the app is running and also in Android Studio, in the preview screen, as I said. Here is an example with vertical orientation and low screen density, as seen on the preview tab of the activity in Android Studio:

[image: Preview screen in Android Studio]

Any idea to fix this isue?

Thanks in advance.

David.

Comment: can you post the code for the whole layout?

Comment: I guess it's long for posting here, @JuanMartinez. I've created a Gist for this activity: https://gist.github.com/dburgosp/69ad5359af0f39590d2261361d72b429

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the problem with your layout. The `transparent_background` view sometimes takes height 0 because its height is `match_parent` and its parent (the `main_relative_layout` view) has its height set as `wrap_content`. You should set the `transparent_background` dimensions relatively to another view, the `LinearLayout` that wraps the content maybe, using `android:layout_alignTop`, `android:layout_alignBottom`, `android:layout_alignLeft` and `android:layout_alignRight` attributes. You may need to remove the `LinearLayout` margin and use padding instead to align the `transparent_background` view correctly, let me know if you need some help.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @JuanMartinez. I've been trying but with no sucess :( I forgot to say that the problem appeared when I included the ScrollView, so I guess the best way to fix this issue is removing the ScrollView and adapting the layout for both orientations and for every screen density, with no need of scroll. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, it makes sense that the problems appears with the ScrollView, because when you added it you had to set the main_relative_layout RelativeLayout height to wrap_content. If you remove the ScrollView and set the RelativeLayout height to match_parent the problem will be gone.